# Reload fragment if current tab is clicked again?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

To navigate in my Android application I use `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`. The content in one of the tabs is changing quite fast.

A user should be able to reload the tab by touching the same item in the action bar again.
Currently the tab content is cached by `ViewPager` and therefore not refreshed if a user clicks on the tab.

As `TabListener.onTabReselected(...)` is fired even if the current tab is already shown, it may be the starting point of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As TabListener.onTabReselected(...) is fired even if the current tab is already shown, it may be the starting point of a solution.

On `onTabReselected()`, call a method on your existing fragment that causes it to refresh its contents.